# How to call a SOAP operation on a specific named WSDL port?

Tags: powershell, soap, wsdl, new-webserviceproxy

Previously when working with calling SOAP web services from PowerShell life's been easy.  Run `$myProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri 'https://example.com/some/web/service.aspx?wsdl'`, then all actions are magically available on the `$myProxy` object.

However, I've recently agreed to help implement a quick script which allows us to send data to the SII web services detailed here: https://www.agenciatributaria.es/AEAT.internet/en_gb/Inicio/Ayuda/Modelos__Procedimientos_y_Servicios/Ayuda_P_G417____IVA__Llevanza_de_libros_registro__SII_/Ayuda_tecnica/Informacion_tecnica_SII/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web/WSDL_de_los_servicios_web.shtml

The non-production web service I'm connecting to should be: https://www7.aeat.es/wlpl/SSII-FACT/ws/fe/SiiFactFEV1SOAP (i.e. received invoices from the previous link).  However, attempting to connect to that URL fails.

I've found a workaround where I can create a proxy using the URI: https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl.  However, the generated proxy does not give me the actions I'd expected to see.  Looking at the underlying WSDL it seems that there are multiple ports specified; some for production, another for test.  I want to ensure that I only connect to the test service.

## Question

How do I ensure that I only connect to the test service?

i.e. For WSDL: https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl

...how do I ensure I only connect to port `SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas`?

## My Code At Present

```
$uri = 'https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl'
$certificate = Get-Item -Path 'Cert:\CurrentUser\My\ABCDEF1234567890' #i.e. this points to the certificate in my certificate store using the thumbprint of the SII certificate
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri 
$proxy.ClientCertificates.Add($certificate)
$proxy.AllowAutoRedirect = $true
```

This works & shows the available operations, but gives no indication on how I'd select only the TEST (`SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas`) port.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you could specify a service's port through the `class` attribute:

```
$url = "http://www.thing.com/stuff.asmx?wsdl"
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy `
  -Uri $url `
  -namespace ... `
  -Class SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas
```

Otherwise, I think it chooses the first port, but don't quote me on that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Adam.  Sadly in this case it's not the web server's listening port; but rather the WSDL port: `<wsdl:port name="SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas" binding="siiWdsl:siiBinding">`.  See https://www2.agenciatributaria.gob.es/static_files/common/internet/dep/aplicaciones/es/aeat/ssii/fact/ws/SuministroFactEmitidas.wsdl for context

Comment: Gotcha. I've seen port types divide functions with-in a service, but I've never seen a port type to provide separate versions of a port group. Lemme change my answer.

Comment: Thanks again.  That works for a port type (e.g. `<wsdl:portType name="siiSOAP">`), but not a port name :/.  It seems that in C# the port names represent themselves as endpoints; i.e. generating a connected service from the WSDL we see the port values appearing under the EndpointConfiguration enum; e.g. `SuministroFactRecibidas.siiSOAPClient.EndpointConfiguration.SuministroFactEmitidasPruebas`